# Shorcut on desktop that enables packet data and 3G

Tags: root-access, battery-life, home-screen-shortcuts, mobile-data

In order to save battery (it works a lot!), 99% of the time I disable packet data and I use only 2G networks, because I don't want the phone to go on internet / use data.

But sometimes I want to use internet, so I have to do :

- 1) **Enable** *Settings > Wireless and networks > Mobile networks > Use packet data*
- 2) **Disable** *Settings > Wireless and networks > Mobile networks > Use only 2G networks*

... and then to do it in the opposite way when the internet session is over.
This is quite long...

---

My question is:

**How to set a shortcut on desktop that does 1) + 2)  in just one single click ?**
(Android 2.3.6)

---

PS : here is what my notification bar looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [widgets](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/adding-widgets-to-android-home-screen/) to your home screen if your phone supports. You can also try widgets from play store like

[2g-3g switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.curvefish.widgets.network2g3gonoff&hl=en)

[Data on or off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.miabit.android.dataonoff&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks ! By the way, is this website safe to download these apps directly as .APK ? : http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/ ?

Answer (score 1):

On most devices shipping with ICS and up, you can simply open the notification area, and tap the corresponding quick-setting:

[image: quick settings]
<sup>Quick settings in the notification bar (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Make your pick. Hint: A2 :)

PS: Not sure how far this is customizable on which Android version. Even items available might depend on the device used. So I'm not sure your device has a 2G/3G toggle in here, but you might check.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Unfortunately my notification bar doesn't look like this. I added a picture of it in my question (see at the end of the question).
Can I add buttons to this bar (for Mobile data), like on your screenshot ?

Comment: I don't think there's a general "yes" or "no" to that question. You might wish to include your device and Android version with your question to shed some light, so you get better fitting answers – as that very much depends on that (plus on things like "Custom ROM" or specific UIs like Touchwiz, Sense, etc. being used ;)

Comment: I have a Samsung Y (S5230) with factory Android Gingerbread 2.3.6 (including TouchWiz by default?)

Comment: I think so, yes (cannot check as I don't have such ;). And please add these details *to your question* so they don't get lost :)